# ID type mismatch when trying to get

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Was just testing my code earlier this morning, and found something I cannot seems to resolve.

My SKU class has a custom ID generator(assinged) to take a String:

```
static mapping = {
    id generator: 'assigned', name: 'sku'
}
```

I created a SKU object with ID: "**1234445**"  (Normally my SKU id is a mixture of dashes letters and numbers, but just for testing purposes I used a number as String)

Now whenever I try to do an SKU.get("**1234445**"), I get the following Error:

> Provided id of the wrong type
>
> Expected: class java.lang.String, got class java.lang.Long

Obviously I provided a String, somehow it's treating it as a Long when .get is performed, hence causing the error.

Any ideas on how to resolve this besides not using a String that looks like a number for SKU.id (Sku.sku in my case)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String id` instead of `String sku`, if want to use `SKU.get("123445")`

```
class SKU {
    String id
    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'assigned'
    }
}

def newSku = new SKU()
newSku.id = '123445'
newSku.save(flush: true)

println SKU.get("123445")
```

If you need to use `sku` specifically as the identifier then use

```
SKU.findBySku("123445")
```

with the mapping you have right now (as mentioned in the question).

Comment: Thanks, sort of having a deja vu right now as I am reading your answer, feels like I've read this before somewhere but somehow it didn't come to me as encountered the error.

Comment: @16dots When you face these kind of blockers, just use `grails console` and try to test things out..... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SKU.get("1234445" as String)
```

should work

Comment: It does not work, still the same error,  I think somehow when it goes into .get, it's converted back into a Long before reaching the database.

Comment: You may get the same problem , but making sure that you're using a strongly typed variable. Try, for instance,

`String key = '1234445';

SKU.get(key);`

Also, remember that '1234445' is a String, while "1234445" is a GString...

Comment: It was like that originally in my code (it was passed into the controller from my view ie:  String key = String.valueOf(1234445) ), and yeah, that's when I was baffled by the error, I tried a few different ways to construct a new String for my use, none of them went through, it's this same error every single time.

Comment: What does `"1234445" as String` mean? Cast a `String` to `String`?

Comment: @dmahapatro - "1234445" is not a String in groovy - it's a GString. '1234445' _is_ a String (note the single quotes vs. the double quotes)

Comment: @dmahapatro - I stand corrected. That's very interesting, and counter-intuitive.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me instead of counter intuitive. GStrings come to picture when we expect a value to be evaluated at runtime. Glad I was able to convince. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the thread necromancy, but I encountered [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47677294/hibernate-force-get-to-respect-the-data-type-of-its-parameter) recently. As it turns out (thanks to [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17123/peter) for the solution) you can workaround the issue by defining `String id` *in addition to* the `String sku`. The following is a little ugly but works:

```
class Sku {
    String id
    String sku
    static mapping = {
        id name: 'sku', generator: 'assigned'
    }
}
```

Then in a Spock test:

```
when:
(new Sku(sku: sku)).save()

then:
Sku.get(sku)

where:
sku << ['12345', 'f00-b4r']
```