# Hibernate: force get() to respect the data type of its parameter

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Setup: Grails 2.5.6 with Hibernate 4.3.10

I have a table with a string id. Thing is, its values are numeric strings, and this seems to mess up `get()` when I pass in a value such as `"000000"`.

Domain class:

```
class Term
{
  static mapping = {
    id name: 'code', generator: 'assigned'
    version false
    code column: 'CODE'
    description column: 'DESC'
  }

  String code
  String description
}
```

Data looks like:

```
CODE   || DESC
-------++---------------------------
000000 || The Beginning of Time
201715 || Post Secondary Winter 2017
201815 || Post Secondary Winter 2018
999999 || The End of Time
```

And then in testing I found the following:

```
assert Term.list()          // works fine
assert !Term.get('foo')     // works fine
//assert Term.get('000000') // throws exception
```

The exception thrown is:

```
Method threw 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException' exception.
Provided id of the wrong type for class Term. Expected: class java.lang.String, got class java.lang.Long
org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class Term. Expected: class java.lang.String, got class java.lang.Long
```

So it looks like at some point the '000000' and the '201715' and whatever else are being inconveniently converted into Long objects. Using `as String` doesn't help either. Can anyone help me tell Hibernate that this String should be treated as a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a Grails bug and I'm guessing it is because you have not declared `id` to be of type `String` in your domain class because it is mapped to a different field (which makes sense).

You could try adding

```
String id
```

to your domain class although that may not caused desired behaviour with column generation.

I would suggest rather than using `get()` you could use `findByCode()` as you have mapped your id to the `code` field and the result should be the same.

Comment: Yes, `findByCode()` worked fine, but I think adding `String id` is the correct workaround. It's ugly, but now `get()` works as expected.

Comment: Ah, glad that worked.  I thought it might try and create/use a column called 'id' despite the mapping

Comment: I haven't tried letting it create the table; it might yet create the `id` column. But the fact that it doesn't look for the column suggests that it's probably smart enough not to. I'm working with existing tables, or else I would use the standard `id` and `version`. Anyway, thanks for your help, @Peter!